# How to delete journal on ext3 network drive

Tags: linux, samba, ext3, journal

Something happened when I was copying files to a ext3 drive (via network, mounted by samba) and I lost ability to write anything to this HDD. After I used **dmesg** command it is explained:

```
db: Current: sense key=0x3
ASC=0x0 ASCQ=0x0
Info fld=0xa2fce10
end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 170905104
EXT3-fs error (device sdb2): read_block_bitmap: Cannot read block bitmap - block_group = 644, block_bitmap = 21102592
Aborting journal on device sdb2.
ext3_abort called.
EXT3-fs error (device sdb2): ext3_journal_start_sb: Detected aborted journal
Remounting filesystem read-only
EXT3-fs error (device sdb2) in ext3_prepare_write: IO failure
__journal_remove_journal_head: freeing b_committed_data
__journal_remove_journal_head: freeing b_committed_data
__journal_remove_journal_head: freeing b_committed_data
__journal_remove_journal_head: freeing b_committed_data
__journal_remove_journal_head: freeing b_committed_data
__journal_remove_journal_head: freeing b_committed_data
```

I investigated problem further and found out tha the journal is probably corrupted. It was suggested that I should: unmount drive, remove journal from filesystem using **tune2sf**, use **e2fsck** to scan drive and lastly recreate journal using **tune2fs**. That's the tricky part becouse the drive is flagged as **needs_revocery** and the journal could'nt be deleted (even when I force delete in **e2fck** it won't allow it). I try to change flag using **debugfs** but the program fails every time:

```
Can't read an block bitmap while reading block bitmap
```

I'm 99% sure that data on drive are not corrupted, and when I use **e2fsck** before I delete the journal it will definitley corrupt some data.

Any ideas how to remove needs_recovery flag from that drive so I will be able to delete journal?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the journal itself. You have an unreadable block (ie: The disk is failing) that corrupted the journal or another metadata, so simply get rid of the journal is **not** the right solution.

I strongly suggest you to backup all you can and to replace the failing disk.

Answer (score 0):

As @shodanshok already said the journal might not be possible to delete anyway since that particular sector is failing. There is a simple rescue: mount the partition as **ext2**, not ext3, so that journal block is not read at all. Then backup all data as quickly as possible. I had the same problem a few days ago.